# Put settings from file into different strings

Tags: loops, streamreader

I have a document containing settings for a program like so

```
setting1;value1;
setting2;value2;
setting3;value3;
```

I want to loop through these lines, assigning value1 from setting1 to a string named the same (setting1). So that the strings value will be value1.. Hope you get me ?

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most sensible way is to store therm in a Dictionary:

```
// untested
Dictionary<string,string> settings = 
    File.Readlines("filename")
    .Select(line => line.Split(";"))
    .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);

// usage:
string value1 = settings["setting1"];
```

If you really want to assign them all to named fields or properties (but not: variables) in one go then you will need Reflection.

Comment: Thanks for this, i didnt even know about Dictionary! A very nice thing to learn indeed! Im still relatively new to C#, but what a great language that is.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading in a lot of these? If there are only a couple, variables might work but if there are a lot, a dictionary or similar might be a good choice. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

You would just need to change your loop to add a new dictionary entry instead - use the 'setting' as the key and the value as the value.

Comment: There is only around 15 different settings, so i could probably just add them as strings manually.. but how do i replace the `Properties.Settings.Default[phraseArr[0]]` with the string name? Something like this i think, but not sure: `string [phraseArr[0]] = phraseArr[1];`

Comment: That will not work or compile. If these settings need using around your program and they need consistent names and you do not want to use an existing data structure, consider creating a new class to store them. A simple class with some properties to set and get them. Then you would create the class before the loop and in your loop set the properties. If you want to use it in this way, then you need to know the names of the settings before hand and where you want to set them. You would need to use a switch statement to then set them (switch on phraseArr[0]).